# Why does BST node not get removed in the case it is the root with a single child?

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I am working on this BST (binary search tree) code challenge:

> Write a `BST` class for a Binary Search Tree. The class should support:
>
> - Inserting values with the `insert` method.
> - Removing values with the `remove` method; this method should only remove the first instance of a given value.
> - Searching for values with the `contains` method.
>
> Note that you can't remove values from a single-node tree. In other words, calling the `remove` method on a single-node tree should simply do nothing.
>
> Each  `BST` node has an integer `value`, a `left` child node, a `right` child node. A node is said to be a valid `BST` node if and only if it satisfies the BST property; its `value` is strictly greater than the values of every node to its left; its `value` is less than or equal to the values of every node to its right; and its children nodes are either valid `BST` nodes themselves or `None` / `null`.
>
> ### Sample Usage
>
> ```
>    // Assume the following BST has already been created:
>
>             10
>           /     \
>          5      15          
>        /   \   /   \ 
>       2     5 13   22
>     /           \
>    1            14
> ```

And I am currently implementing the `remove` method. This is my code:

```
class BST:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def insert(self, value):
        if self is None:
            self = BST(value)
        if value < self.value:
            if self.left is not None:
                self.left.insert(value)
            else: 
                self.left = BST(value)
        if value >= self.value:
            if self.right is not None:
                self.right.insert(value)
            else: 
                self.right = BST(value)
        return self

    def contains(self, value):
        if self == None:
            return False
        if self.value == value:
            return True
        if value < self.value:
            if self.left is not None:
                return self.left.contains(value)
        if value > self.value:
            if self.right is not None:
                return self.right.contains(value)
        return False

   def remove(self, value, parent=None):
        if self is None:
            return self
        elif value < self.value:
            if self.left is not None:
                self.left.remove(value,self)
        elif value > self.value:
            if self.right is not None:
                self.right.remove(value,self)
        elif value == self.value:
            if self.right is None and self.left is None:
                if parent is None:
                    pass
                else:
                    if parent.left == self:
                        parent.left = None
                    if parent.right == self:
                        parent.right = None
            elif self.right is None:
                if parent is None:
                    self = self.left
                else:
                    if parent.left == self:
                        parent.left = self.left
                    if parent.right == self:
                        parent.right = self.left
            elif self.left is None:
                if parent is None:
                    self = self.right
                else:
                    if parent.left == self:
                        parent.left = self.right
                    if parent.right == self:
                        parent.right = self.right
            elif self.right is not None and self.left is not None:
                sub = self.right.minguy()
                self.value = sub
                self.right.remove(sub,self)
                pass
        return self

    def minguy(self):
        while (self.left is not None):
            self = self.left
        return self.value
```

### The problem

Consider this degenerate tree:

```
  1
   \
    2
     \
      3
       \
        4
```

...and we have to remove 1. Why does simply `self = self.right` not do the removing job?

I was expecting 2 to be the root and 1 to not exist and the tree to end up like:

```
    2
     \
      3
       \
        4
```

Specifically this code:

```
        elif self.left is None:
            if parent is None:
                self = self.right
            else:
                if parent.left == self:
                    parent.left = self.right
                if parent.right == self:
                    parent.right = self.right
```

Here is the code that tests my implementation:

```
import program
import unittest

BST = program.BST

class TestProgram(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_case_1(self):
        root = BST(1)
        root.insert(2)
        root.insert(3)
        root.insert(4)
        root.remove(1)

        self.assertTrue(not root.contains(1))
        self.assertTrue(root.value == 2)   # This test fails!
        self.assertTrue(root.contains(3))
```

Comment: Please post the code necessary to re-create the case you describe.

Comment: unfortunately i dont have it :( im kinda doing it on problem solving platforms. Is that bad? 

The problem statement is 1 -> 2 ->3->4 all right children with root 1

Comment: If you cannot create the case described, how do you know your code does not handle it properly?

Comment: wait i have test case but i am just struggling to put it in the question as a code snippet

Comment: What does the notation `->` mean for a binary tree?

Comment: And to be clear: you are asking why *your code* works properly, but a certain modification would break it?

Comment: -> means right child. its a binary search tree. And when i am trying to remove 2 it breaks so the case of removing a node which only has one child

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/6KilXHC

this is the difference between expected output and my output, for context.

Comment: The image is about another deletion than you have given in the question. The problem depicted in the image relates to attempts to delete the *root* of a tree. Your code does not achieve that. Assigning to `self` has no effect on the tree. That is merely a local variable you assign to.

Comment: Although that is a problem, we need to know what the **program** is that would test whether the removal of a root value would work correctly. Is the caller of `remove` supposed to get the new root in return? Do you have a second class that manages the root? Do you have an agreement that a root node may have a `None` value and that this would depict an empty tree? How is an empty tree represented? Etc, etc. We need more information.

Comment: wait you kind of answered my question trincot... in the first comment you put. if i pass root in a method and if the method is

def something(self):
    self = self.right

and if i call it on
root = BST()
 root.something()
will it become null or stay the same?

Comment: i am really sorry for not being too good with the platform and not providing what i am supposed to be in the main question.. its my first day here after months of reading and im learning. My bad. I will try to get the program that tests it (i am on leetcode kind of platform that tests cases for me)

Comment: Like I wrote before, the requirements for your class (more than one?) and methods are not entirely clear. I asked a few questions that should be clarified.

Comment: hey everyone, i think i added the test code corresponding to the one that is not working in my case. here is also the error screenshot message i guess.. 
https://imgur.com/a/oreGMyc

did i do it right? do you have any more questions?

Comment: Your test code constructs `BST`. Please add the `BST` class with the constructor and `insert` method, whatever is needed for us to run the test code (and not more).

Comment: Added them as well.

Comment: Thanks. Now to my previous questions: how would you represent an empty tree? What if you remove the only node that is present in the tree, then what is `root` supposed to be?

Comment: Also, your `remove` code *returns* something, like `return self`. Yet the testing code does not look at what is returned. Is the method wrong, or is the testing code wrong?

Comment: The remove method should definitely return self after the removing. But in testing i thought it would update it automatically for example in this BST  1->2->3->4. and i remove 1 and return self it should automatically update self to 2->3->4. Am i wrong?

Comment: So is the testing code *your* testing code? Then I believe your testing code is wrong. If it is intended that `remove` returns `self`, then why is your testing code not using the return value? (And yes, you are wrong in that assumption)

Comment: Also to respond to the previous question i think no tree/no root should be None and one root should be node with the value. This is my understanding, please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: That depends on what you were asked to do (or is this just your own project?). In a good design you would have *two* classes: one for a node and one for a tree (two different concepts).

Comment: hnmmm then i guess  should i update my test code to 

``` self = self.remove(1) ``` ?

Comment: sorry for the bad design and organization. i am trying to solve an algorithm question on platforms like leetcode etc about BST removal thats the context.

Comment: There is no `self` there. You would get further with `root = root.remove(1)`, but it all depends on which tree design you need, and best practice. If you are asking in the context of LeetCode, then you will get more useful answers when you mention that, with a description of the code challenge, ...etc. Now it is all a bit vague to be honest.

Comment: so if we do with root= root.remove(1) what happens? and second, it is a private/you can only access platform after paying, otherwise i would link it right away. I can post the problem if you want with a screenshot.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking with "what happens"? Yes, please share the description of the challenge, so it is clear whether a two-class implementation is expected, how an empty tree is represented, what the signature is of the methods that will be called,...etc.

Comment: yes let me give you problem statement 
https://imgur.com/a/XzBcyUX
this is screenshot of the description and the second image is sandbox. Thats all in the problem statement. Does it help?

Comment: It helps, but this should really be included in your question, and not as image, but as text. Can you update?

Comment: OK, I see you immediately went silent again ;-) I have updated your question.

Comment: Oh sorry, i am afraid here because its my first time here so im worried if i did something wrong or to get banned or people think its not a good questions, first steps. Sorry about the delay. Should I still add the text of the problem in my question?

Comment: No problem. I already edited your question. If you have more text that could be relevant, please add it. Also note I posted an answer below. Would appreciate your review of it.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. It helped a lot and I appreciate all the efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does simply `self = self.right` not do the removing job?

That is indeed the statement that is at the core of the problem. `self` is a local name, and thus `self =` only assigns something to that local name. Assignments to names can never mutate your tree. To mutate a tree, you need assignments to *attributes*, not *names*.

#### Quick solution

In the special case where you need to remove the root node (and don't have a `parent` node whose `left` or `right` attribute to alter), and where that root has exactly one child, you must realise that you cannot change what the caller's `root` name refers to. Whatever you do, the caller's `root` will still reference the original root node. So you have to *update* that root node's attributes.

There are at least two ways to do that:

- Either you apply the `minguy` logic also when the node has only a right child, and you do the "mirrored" action (i.e. implement `maxguy`) for when the node only has a left child, or...
- overwrite *all* the root's attributes (`left`, `right` and `value`) so it becomes a copy of its only child. That child thus becomes disconnected and is therefore deleted instead of the root node.

Here is what you need to change to implement the second idea:

First add a helper method to get a copy from another node:

```
    def copy_from(self, other):
        self.value = other.value
        self.left = other.left
        self.right = other.right
```

Then replace this:

```
self = self.left
```

...with:

```
self.copy_from(self.left)
```

And replace:

```
self = self.right
```

...with:

```
self.copy_from(self.right)
```

This will fix your issue.

#### Remarks

- You have code that tests whether `self` is `None`, but this will never happen when your methods are called as methods. I suppose that the testing suite will not call these functions in another way.
- `elif self.right is not None and self.left is not None:` -- this is the only case that is left over after all previous conditions, so this could be just an `else:`
- When dealing with nodes it is not necessary to explicitly compare with `None`. You can just do `if self.left:` and `if not self.left:`, ...etc.
- If you allow `remove` to *return* a node, then you can do it without the `parent` parameter, simplifying the code:

  ```
      def remove(self, value):
          if value < self.value:
              if self.left:
                  self.left = self.left.remove(value)
          elif value > self.value:
              if self.right:
                  self.right = self.right.remove(value)
          elif value == self.value:
              if not self.right and not self.left:
                  return None
              elif not self.right or not self.left:
                  self.copy_from(self.left or self.right)
              else:
                  self.value = self.right.minguy()
                  self.right = self.right.remove(self.value)
          return self
  ```
- Concerning the code challenge, I must say this is an inferior challenge. It says that *"you can't remove values from a single-node tree"*. That is of course nonsense, and is inspired by a limited vision on how to implement trees. They force you into a certain implementation where a tree must be initialised with one value immediately, and this is because they make no difference between the concept of a node and the concept of a tree. Yet, there is a difference. The notion of an empty tree exists and there is really no good reason why we should not be able to represent an empty tree, or create one for that matter.

  The better way to implement a tree is to *distinguish* the concept of a node and a tree. Both deserve a class. But it wouldn't work with the kind of tests they have prepared, and so they enforce an inferior design.